# Is there anyway to change the size of the buttons of my options menu?

Tags: android

I just have one button in my options menu and I was trying to do it smaller but I can't change it. It just appear in one size, is it possible to change it, or there is no way to do it because the size it's already predefined?

Answer (score 0):

You used any icon for that , if you used just remove it !! that you can do in the menu xml  "android:icon" !! It may help.